# SoapUI Open Source - run teststep from another testsuite in your testsuite teardown script

Tags: soapui

I'm able to run a **testcase** teardown script in my testsuite (TS1) that runs a teststep from another testsuite (TS2) with the following groovy script:

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuites["TS2"].testCases["TC2"].testSteps["STEP2"].run(testRunner, context);
```

But as this teststep should run for all my testcases in TS1, I need to add the teardown script for each testcase which is a bit cumbersome.

I want to know if I could achieve the same thing directly from the **testsuite** teardown script, which would save me a lot of script maintenance.

Unfortunately the **testrunner object** is not available at testsuite level, but I don't know how (or if it's possible) to do it using the **runner object** which is available.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It's possible to execute a *test case* from the tear-down script. What if you moved your test step into it's own test case and do it that way?

Comment: Do you mean to run a testcase (with the teststep included) from within another testsuite teardown script? If so, could you point me out how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

On my first look, I couldn't find a way of executing a single *test step* from a test suite tear down script, but it's possible to execute a *test case* this way. So, if you created a test case and put your single test step inside, you could execute it this way:

```
def testCase = testSuite.project
        .getTestSuiteByName("Expanded TestSuite")
        .getTestCaseByName("TestCase")

def properties = new com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap ()
testCase.run(properties, false)
```

Here, I'm using the sample projects that come with soapUI. The tear down script is attached to the *Simple TestSuite* and is invoking a *TestCase* in the *Expanded TestSuite*.